# Vim: Replace first word on each line of selection with number in list

Tags: vim

I have a large file containing a selection with jumbled numbers. It's supposed to be a seqeunce 1, 2, 3, ... but a few lines got screwed up. I would like to change something like

> foo
>
> bar
>
> 1 foobar
>
> 12345 foobar
>
> 6546458 foobar
>
> 4 foobar

to

> foo
>
> bar
>
> 1 foobar
>
> 2 foobar
>
> 3 foobar
>
> 4 foobar

I know I can use something like `3,$` to select the lines I care about and `put = range(1,1000)` to make new lines starting with the numbers I want, but I want to put these numbers on lines that currently have data, not new lines. The jumbled numbers are several characters long, but always one word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
function Replace()
    let n = 1 
    for i in range(0, line('$'))
        if match(getline(i), '\v^\d+\s') > -1
            execute i . 's/\v^\d+/\=n/'
            let n = n + 1 
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

It traverses the whole file, check if each line begins with a number followed by a space character and does the substitution with the counter that increments with each change.

Call it like:

```
:call Replace()
```

That in your example yields:

```
foo
bar
1 foobar
2 foobar
3 foobar
4 foobar
```

Comment: Works great. I didn't mention this in my post, but I had some lines in my header that I didn't want to modify, but changing the range(0, ...) to start at my data fixed it just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following:

```
:let i=1
:g/^\d\+/s//\=i/|let i=i+1
```

#### Overview

Setup some variable (`let i=1`) to use as our counter. On every line that starts with a number (`:g/^\d\+/`) we execute a substitution (`:s//\=i/`) to replace the pattern with our counter (`\=i`) and then increment our counter (`let i=i+1`).

#### Why use `:g` at all? Why not just `:s`?

You could do this with just a substitution command however the sub-replace-expression, `\=`, needs an expression to evaluate to a value (see `:h sub-replace-expression`). As `let i = i + 1` is a statement it will not be useful.

There are a few ways to overcome this issue:

- Create a function that increments a variable and then returns it
- Use an array instead and then alter the number inside (in-place) then return the value out of the array. e.g. `map(arr, 'v:val+1')[0]`
- If you only have 1 substitution per line then do the `:g` trick from above

Full example using in-place array modification:

```
:let i=[1]
:%s/^\d\+/\=map(i,'v:val+1')[0]
```

Personally, I would use whatever method you can remember.

#### More help

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h :g
:h :let
:h expr
:h map(
:h v:val
```

Comment: Works great using the :g trick, thanks. I had to change it to :17,$g ... in my file because I had a few lines in the header that started with number that I didn't want to modify, but I obviously didn't include that in my prompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\d\+\s  -- Searches for the first occurrence
ciw0<Esc> -- Replaces the word under cursor with "0"
yiw       -- Copies it
:g//norm viwp^Ayiw
          -- For each line that matches the last search pattern,
          --   Replace the current word with copied text,
          --   Increment it,
          --   Copy the new value.
```

(`<Esc>` is just <kbd>Esc</kbd>. `^A` is entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

- `ciw` -- Change inner word. [(`:help c`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#c)
- `:g` -- Global search. [(`:help :g`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g)
- `viw` -- Select inner word. [(`:help v`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v)
- `p` -- Paste (replacing selection) [(`:help v_p`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#v_p)
- `^A` -- Increment. [(`:help CTRL-A`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#CTRL-A)
- `yiw` -- Yank inner word. [(`:help y`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#y)